# SP2013 incorrect credential cached in VS2012

Tags: sharepoint-2013

When I try to deploy to SP2013 I get the following error:

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': The System Account cannot perform this action
```

At some point earlier in time I put the farm setup user details into a login popup for the remote site. Unfortunately these details are cached somewhere and I cannot find where or update them.

Anyone enlighten me as to where they reside?

Ed

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is using Windows' Credential Manager to store credentials. Check

CONTROL PANEL | ALL CONTROL PANEL ITEMS | CREDENTIAL MANAGER.

The credential you're looking for should be listed in the 'generic credentials' section

Answer (score 0):

This is the real cause of error:

When you are logged in as system account (local administrator) , and you are trying to install and deploy the SharePoint app above error will appear.

This is a change in SharePoint 2013 RTM that system account are no longer supported to deploy or purchase any app from the market. It was supported in RT but it’s now prohibited because of security reason.

For more detail please check below link:

http://aanuwizard.com/2012/12/07/article-14-from-30-system-account-can-not-deploy-or-purchase-an-app-in-sharepoint-2013-rtm/